# Logging in Java Desktop app

Tags: java, error-logging

I'm developing a Java desktop app and was wondering what are the best practices for logging bugs and exceptions. I'd like to log the exceptions in a file that's sent to me when there's a problem.
Are there any good frameworks for doing this or is it a retarded idea?
Thanks a lot

Elsanto 696

Answer (score 4):

[log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/index.html) is the de facto standard (with the standard [Java logging framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/) a close second).

You should use Version 1.2.x for production use.

You can configure log4j via code (at runtime) or via a configuration file (either Java properties or XML format).

From the website:

> The target of the log output can be a file, an OutputStream, a java.io.Writer, a remote log4j server, a remote Unix Syslog daemon, or many other output targets.

There is a SMTPAppender that can be configured for sending mails with log entries on specific conditions, in case eMail is what you meant by "sent to me".

Comment: You should consider using the Java logging framework instead of log4j, to avoid an extra dependency.

Answer (score 3):

[log4J is better framework to log](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/)

[Here is good tutorial and article on log4j](http://www.java-tips.org/java-tutorials/tutorials/log4j-revealing-the-full-power-part2.html)

Answer (score 3):

There are various [Java Logging Frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_logging_framework) out there. Pick one!

- [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/).
- [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/).
- [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/).
- [java.util.logging](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html).

Comment: shame on you for leaving out java.util.logging :)

Comment: SLF4J isn't a logging framework itself, but rather a facade for plugging in different logging engines.  It's the spiritual replacement for Apache Commons Logging.  The irony is that a large number of Apache projects use SLF4J instead of their own Commons Logging.

Comment: There's also JCL (Java Commons Logging).

Answer (score 1):

Java4 Logging works pretty well, though it lacks some of the features in Log4j. The real problem is sending data from a user's PC to you directly - you would probably have to get their permission for this. The usual approach is to log to a file, and have the user give you that file in the event that there is a problem.